# Find sum of cells that have the same value in their adjacent cells (Excel)

Tags: excel

Apologies if this is too basic, I'm not experienced with Excel. However, lots of web searching has not turned up an answer to this problem.

In Microsoft Excel I have two columns, one contains an hour of a day (just the hour, I have removed the minutes), the other contains a numeric value. I want to find the sum of all of the numeric values which have the same hour of the day adjacent to them. So for example this table:

```
10  3.3
10  18.49
10  3.17
10  9.6
10  10.5
09  12.6
09  6.6
09  3.3
09  3.3
09  16.65
```

would turn into this table:

```
10 45.06
09 42.45
```

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the range A2:B11 and D2=10, then try this...

In E2

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$11,D2,$B$2:$B$11)
```

and copy down to E3.

You can also achieve the desired output with the help of pivot table as stated by Scott.

Refer to the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sumif
for example your hours in column A
your numbers in Column B

copy all Data in column A  and paste it a new column E for example and Select the new Data and Remove Duplicates under Data Tab
in F1 write:
`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,E1,$B$1:$B$10)`
Change A1:A10 to your data in column A, hour
Change B1:B10 to your data in column B, numeric
Keep $ for absolute references
and you can drag the formula

If you want the result in column C for example near your Data with hours starting in A2, You can use in C2:
`=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11)))`